# Android thumbnail generation differs between MINI_KIND and MICRO_KIND

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am currently working on an application that lists all the images (thumbnails) on the device's sdcard.  Here is a code snippet:

```
final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, null);
imageColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplication().getContentResolver(),
            imageCursor.getInt(imageColumnIndex),MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

The issue I am seeing is that the image displayed is not the thumbnail of the big image.  Moreover, if I make the call to `MINI_KIND` instead, I am getting the right thumbnail.  I am currently testing this on a HTC Aria.  Since the application needs to support 2.1 (API level 7), I cannot take use of the ThumbnailUtil class.

Any advice would be beneficial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the thumbnail database where MINI_KIND is getting the images from was corrupted in the database.  Deleting the files from the SD Card seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Just for the record: there are other problems with `MICRO_KIND` (or rather the Samsung media stuff?), too: on my Galaxy Gio (API:10), I found them simply missing (empty cursor querying for them, while `MINI_KIND` is fine).